Chromium security warning while running Behat test without headless mode
My problem
I am using Behat and Chromium (without Selenium) locally for running web tests for my application. But recently, when adding a security feature to my application, I got the "The information you're about to submit is not secure" warning.
I would like this warning to not show up while running my automated tests.
I've noticed that when running Chromium in headless mode, there are no problems.
However, I would like to run it without headless mode to debug my Behat tests.
What I've tried
I've tried to add a self-signed certificate, but Chromium still shows me the error. I've tried to add options when launching Chromium using the terminal (--ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-web-security, ...) but nothing seems to work. I also tried changing the Chromium security settings but the warning still shows up. Finally, I wrote scenarios for clicking on the "Send anyway" button but it still doesn't work (and it fails when running tests in headless mode because there is no warning).
My Configuration
...
Behat\MinkExtension:
    browser_name: chrome
    base_url: http://www.mybox-behat.docker #added in /etc/hosts
    sessions:
        default:
            chrome:
                api_url: '127.0.0.1:9222'

Do you guys have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance!
